# How to insert large array object in mongoose mongodb collection with the help of node worker thread?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, worker-thread

I want to insert a large array object in a Mongoose collection with the help of node worker thread, but it is not responding. I tried it without node worker thread and it's working fine, but with worker thread it's not working.

This is my worker file `worker.js`:

```js
const { isMainThread, parentPort } = require("worker_threads");
const User = require("./models/user");
const csv = require("csvtojson");
if (!isMainThread) {
  console.log("In Worker Thread");

  parentPort.on("message", (csvFilePath) => {
    csv()
      .fromFile(csvFilePath)
      .then((jsonObj) => {
        User.insertMany(jsonObj)
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            parentPort.postMessage("result");
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            parentPort.postMessage("error");
            console.log(err);
          });
      });
  });
}
```

This is my main tread file. From here I am sending the data CSV file path. With that path, I will read the CSV file and convert it to the array of JSON. I want to insert this array into a MongoDB collection with the help of Mongoose.

```
// main thread file
const app = require("express")();
const formidable = require("formidable");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("./models/user");
const csv = require("csvtojson");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fileUpload", {
  useNewUrlParser: "true",
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
mongoose.connection.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("err", err);
});
mongoose.connection.on("connected", (err, res) => {
  console.log("mongoose is connected");
});

const { isMainThread, Worker } = require("worker_threads");
let worker;
if (isMainThread) {
  console.log("In main thread");
  worker = new Worker("./worker.js");
  worker.on("message", (data) => {
    // console.log("Got Message=>", data);
  });
  worker.on("error", (data) => {});
  worker.on("exit", (data) => {});
}

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  worker.postMessage("from main thread");
  res.status(200).json("Hellow World");
});

app.post("/upload", (req, res, next) => {
  const form = formidable({ multiples: true });

  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
      return;
    }
    const csvFilePath = files.file.path;

    csv()
      .fromFile(csvFilePath)
      .then((jsonObj) => {
        console.log(jsonObj);
        worker.postMessage(csvFilePath);
        worker.on("message", (data) => {
          res.json({ fields, files, data });
        });
      });
  });
});

app.listen(5001, () => {
  console.log("Server Is Running");
});
```